# Copper tubing on refrigerator is leaking

Tags: plumbing

Copper tubing is leaking at both connections (refrigerator and wall).

Do I use new couplings or will old ones work?

Answer (score 1):

If it was a new install new ones should've been used. Make sure the fittings are tight. I really wouldn't use the old fittings which are most likely compression fittings